# Jackson JSON deserialisation of Scala Option[AnyVal]

Tags: json, scala, jackson

I want to use Jackson for deserialisation of JSON in Scala case classes where there are some `Option[_ <: AnyVal]` classes.

I know there are plenty of other serialisers out there specifically for Scala, but **the requirement here is to use Jackson.**

I've found this which I am trying to follow: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/wiki/FAQ

The following **will** work:

```
case class MyValue @JsonCreator() (@(JsonValue @getter) value: Int) extends AnyVal

case class MyWrapper(@JsonDeserializer(contentAs = classOf[MyValue]) myInt: Option[MyValue])

val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
mapper.registerModule(new DefaultScalaModule)

mapper.readValue("{\"myInt\": 5}", classOf[MyWrapper])
```

However, if `MyValue` wrapped a `String` then it fails unless I change the `contentAs` to a `String`:

```
case class MyValue @JsonCreator() (@(JsonValue @getter) value: String) extends AnyVal

case class MyWrapper(@JsonDeserializer(contentAs = classOf[String]) myInt: Option[MyValue])
```

It looks like if `MyValue` wraps a primitive type like `int`, `long`, ...then the `contentAs` should be `MyValue`, else it should be the type that its wrapper. The documentation doesn't mention anything about this, it's something I've come up with whilst playing around.

My question is - what is the rule here? Am I even doing this correctly?

**EDIT:**

I've been playing around and it turns out that I don't think you need the the `@JsonDeserializer` at all - which is contrary to the advice from the wiki...can anyone shed any light?

It would appear that you only need the ones on the `AnyVal` classes:

```
case class MyValue @JsonCreator() (@(JsonValue @getter) value: Int) extends AnyVal
case class MyRefValue @JsonCreator() (@(JsonValue @getter) value: BigDecimal) extends AnyVal
```